# Sinatra, Mongoid, Heroku, MongoHQ: connecting to Mongodb

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

Trying to get Mongoid up and running with Sinatra on Heroku (MongoHQ). Previous experience with Rails but first time with the stack and Sinatra.

Started with one of the simple examples on the web (`app.rb`):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'mongo'
require 'mongoid'

configure do
  Mongoid.load!('mongoid.yml')

  Mongoid.configure do |config|
    if ENV['MONGOHQ_URL']
      conn = Mongo::Connection.from_uri(ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'])
      uri = URI.parse(ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'])

      # problem happens here 
      config.master = conn.db(uri.path.gsub(/^\//, ''))
    else
      config.master = Mongo::Connection.from_uri("mongodb://localhost:27017").db('test')
    end
  end
end


# Models
class Counter
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :count, :type => Integer

  def self.increment
    c = first || new({:count => 0})
    c.inc(:count, 1)
    c.save
    c.count
  end
end

# Controllers
get '/' do
  "Hello visitor n" + Counter.increment.to_s
end
```

For reference, `mongoid.yml` looks like:

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: localhost
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

As per `app.rb (# problem happens here)`, my logs say:

```
/app/app.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `master=' for Mongoid::Config:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.3/lib/mongoid.rb:112:in `configure'
from /app/app.rb:11:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1273:in `configure'
from /app/app.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
```

I have also tried variants, including:

```
config.master = Mongo::Connection.from_uri(ENV['MONGOHQ_URL']).db('appXXXXX')
Mongoid.database = Mongo::Connection.from_uri(ENV['MONGOHQ_URL']).db('appXXXXXXX')
```

But get the same error:

```
undefined method `master` for Mongoid::Config:Module (NoMethodError)
```

or:

```
undefined method `database=` for Mongoid::Config:Module (NoMethodError)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So was using Mongoid 3.x ... which:

- Doesn't use 10gen driver: uses Moped
- Doesn't use `config.master`

The canonical sample code above which is all over the web works out of the box with Mongoid 2.x so have dropped back to that for the time being.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't be

```
configure do
  Mongoid.load!('mongoid.yml')
end
```

enough?

That's what the [mongid docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#configuration) are saying. The `MONGOHQ_URL` environment variable already contains every information to initialize the connection to the db.

Comment: Thanks @iltempo :) I figured out the problem, just writing up the answer.